# Function parameters - Python

Tags: python

```
def parrot(voltage, state='a stiff', action='voom', type='Norwegian Blue'):
    print "-- This parrot wouldn’t", action
    print "if you put", voltage, "volts through it."
    print "-- Lovely plumage, the", type
    print "-- It’s", state, "!"
```

I started learning python. I can call this function using parrot(5,'dead') and parrot(voltage=5). But why can't I call with the same function with parrot(voltage=5, 'dead')?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't use a non-keyword argument (`'arg_value'`) after a keyword argument (`arg_name='arg_value'`). This is because of how Python is designed.

See here: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments

Therefore, you must enter all arguments following a keyword-argument as keyword-arguments...

```
# instead of parrot(voltage=5, 'dead'):
parrot(voltage=5, state='dead')

# or:
parrot(5, state='dead')

# or:
parrot(5, 'dead')
```

Comment: parrot(5, state='dead') would also be valid